# Find top counted element in a dictionary of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionary myDict:

```
myDict = { 'cow': {'A':2, 'B':5, 'C':3},
           'cat': {'A':7, 'B':1, 'C':6},
           'dog': {'A':1, 'B':4, 'C':3},
           'bird': {'A':5, 'B':7, 'C':9}
         }
```

I want to find the top count element for each animal in this case, i.e. the output should be:

```
myNewTable = {'cow':'B', 'cat':'A', 'dog':'B', 'bird':'C'}
```

I tried to achieve this using the following code:

```
 myNewTable = max(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0] for x in myDict
```

but got the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-11-3bcb909a6476>", line 28
    myNewTable = max(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0] for x in myDict
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What did I do wrong here ? And how could I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using comprehension syntax but haven't wrapped it in a specific type (e.g. `list => []`, `set => {}`, `dict => {:}`). So fixing your code it would look like:

```
In []:
[max(myDict[x].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0] for x in myDict]

Out[]:
['B', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

But you wanted it as a `dict`, so perhaps you meant:

```
In []:
{x: max(myDict[x].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0] for x in myDict}

Out[]:
{'bird': 'C', 'cat': 'A', 'cow': 'B', 'dog': 'B'}
```

But can be specified more succinctly (as per @coldspeed's answer):

```
{x: max(myDict[x], key=myDict[x].get) for x in myDict}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, your syntax is wrong, but you have the right idea. A nice and succinct solution using `max` and `dict.get` can be built on by iterating over `myDict`:

```
>>> {k : max(v, key=v.get) for k, v in myDict.items()}
{'bird': 'C', 'cat': 'A', 'cow': 'B', 'dog': 'B'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with its [`.most_common(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> {k: Counter(v).most_common(1)[0][0] for k, v in myDict.items()}
{'cat': 'A', 'bird': 'C', 'cow': 'B', 'dog': 'B'}
```

This will be useful in general **if you want to select more than one highest count elements from the nested dict**. For example, below is the sample to select list of two most common keys in dict:

```
>>> {k: [x[0] for x in Counter(v).most_common(2)] for k, v in myDict.items()}
{'dog': ['B', 'C'], 'bird': ['C', 'B'], 'cat': ['A', 'C'], 'cow': ['B', 'C']}
```

---

From the [**`Counter.most_common([n])`** document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

> Return a `list` of the `n` most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If `n` is omitted or `None`, `most_common()` returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily: